# Node Labels in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

Just looking for an understanding on how node labels work with regards to HDFS. I understand processing using yarn with limited set of nodes defined under node labels. How is it managed at HDFS level? Say i have 40 nodes and assign 20 nodes for a node label.

1. Will data be copied over from one node to another node for processing?
2. Will data reside only in those nodes under node labels.

Trying hard to get materials on the above topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the node labels are only for YARN processing. A data processing may or may not have the data available local. In that case data will be streamed from the other node. The processing time will be affected. Based on the use case, the Labeling may or may not be useful.